# How to rebase a branch off a rebased branch?

Tags: git, branch, rebase, git-rebase

So my history looks like this:

`o---o---o---o  master
     \
      o---o---o  A
               \
                o B`

So, to explain:

- I have branch `A` which was started from `master`
- I have branch `B` (with only 1 commit) which was started from `A`

What I want is this:

`o---o---o---o  master
             \
              o---o---o  A
                       \
                        o B`

---

What I did was:

1).

`git checkout A
git rebase master`

This resulted in a lot of conflicts which, after some significant time spent fixing, the following history emerged:

`o---o---o---o  master
             \
              o---o---o  A`

Which is exactly what I wanted.

(I don't know where `B` is right now)

---

2).

After this I did a lot of squashes and changed the order of commits on `A`, to make the history look like I want.

---

3).

Now, what I also want to do is:

`git checkout B
git rebase A`

However this doesn't seem to work and I don't know why. If I do `git log` I see the commits which were there before I did step 1.

Also, I get the same huge number of conflicts which I already solved at step 1. I spent significant time doing it, don't want to do it again.

[This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27445747/how-to-rebase-over-already-rebased-branch) suggested to use `--onto`, which I did:

`git checkout B
git rebase --onto A`

But this deletes the commit on `B` entirely and makes `A` and `B` point to the same commit i.e. the last one on `A`.

---

My question is: **How can I effectively rebase B off A so that it looks like B started from A** ? (which was actually true in the beginning).

My best guess is that I'm using `--onto` wrong. Or that I should use something else (like `cherry-pick`).

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Short answer to **How can I effectively rebase B off A so that it looks like B started from A?**
<sub>Assuming you want to move *exactly one* commit:</sub>

```
git rebase --onto A B~ B
```

<sub>If you want to move *more then one* commit use:</sub>

```
git rebase --onto A old_A B
```

**The rest of the answer.**

Your branch of B is still around (you can check it out), but its parent is still the exact commit object that `A` was before.
to see a graphical representation of this I use:

```
git log --graph --decorate --all
```

to see all branches and where they are with respect to each other.

What you originally had:

```
o---o---o---o  master
     \
      o---o---o  A
               \
                o B
```

What you have now:

```
o---o---o-----------o  master
     \               \
      o---o---o(B~)   o---o---o A
               \
                o B
```

In terms of using `--onto`, you need to have a starting point and an ending point.
use:

```
git rebase --onto [target] [rebasing stops] [rebasing head]
git rebase --onto A B~ B
```

And what you get:

```
o---o---o----------o  master
     \              \
      o---o---o      o---o---o A
            (old_A)           \
                               o B
```

`[branch_name]~` indicates the parent commit of the branch.

The `B~` is the branch that you do not want to change.  (It happens to be the old `A`)

Alternatively, if B was the only commit that had A as a parent, (i.e., B is the end of a chain of commits that branch off master) you could do

```
git checkout B
git rebase master
git checkout B~   # this is the commit before B (the A commit)
git branch -d A   # remove the old A branch (it was rebased, and so is now invalid
git branch A      # recreate the A branch on the commit that is based on the original A
```

Comment: Thank you. `git rebase --onto A B~ B` worked **PERFECTLY**. Now all I have to figure out is why :) :D

Comment: Note for those blindly copy-pasting (as I did): the second argument needs to point to `old A`, so `B~` only works if `B` has a single commit - which here, it does. I like to think of the syntax as `git rebase --onto <new base> <old base> <head>`; `<old base>` is where `<head>` currently branches from, and `<new base>` is where you want it to branch from.

Answer (score 33):

I have the same issue of my git flow, and I found a best and fast way to do it.

(1) Project history in the beginning:

```
    master ---A---B---C
                \
                 D---E---F feature1
                          \
                           G---H feature2
```

(2) Rebase feature1 onto master and force pushed:

```
    master ---A---B------------------------C
                \                           \
                 D---E---F feature1(old)     D---E---F feature1
                          \
                           G---H feature2
```

(3) Rebase feature2 onto featrue1 (the new one)

```
    master ---A---B------------------------C
                                            \
                                             D---E---F feature1
                                                      \
                                                       G---H feature2
```

The most confused part is how to do **(3)** .. but no one has a clear answer of doing it.

I believe many people encountered the same issue as I did, when we were trying to do "rebase --onto", we found that **feature1(old)** is actually not existing!

```
    git rebase --onto feature1 feature1(old) feature2
```

**Solution is to use below instead:**

```
    git rebase --onto feature1 feature1@{1} feature2
```

> The syntax feature1@{1} means "the last known state of feature1 before the rebase", answer is refereed from https://coderwall.com/p/xzsr9g/rebasing-dependent-branches-with-git

Comment: Hmmm, interesting, I'll look more into this part, thanks.

Comment: thanks, this helped since in my exact situation, `feature1(old)` branch no longer exists after the first rebase from `feature1(old)` to `feature1`, presumably due to the force push

Answer (score 2):

If you have already re-based A. It should be the case that B is exactly where you left it. The branch (a pointer) that was A has simply moved to it's new location.

What I would recommend to effectively rebase B onto A is, as you suggested, to use 'cherry-pick'. This command attempts to apply the changes made in a commit to the branch on which you run it.

So if the commit IDs of the commit to which B originally pointed was '123456' then I would recommend moving your current 'B' to the same place as the new 'A' with `git branch -f B A` then run `git cherry-pick 123456` which will apply the changes onto A.

I believe the `--onto` flag is used to set the target location from which to apply the commits.It defaults to "upstream" (source: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

The way I like to think of the rebase command is as follows:

```
git rebase --onto <Starting here> <Apply all commits from HERE> <TO HERE>
```

Using this, it would probably have been simpler to rebase B onto master, then point A to the commit preceding B.

```
git rebase master B
```

(as the start point (--onto) is implicitly 'master')

then to use `git branch -f A B^` (the ^ means 'the parent of')